# has anyone ever used the admob on windows phone 8.1 silverlight and it worked?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, admob

I have a completed application and I want to publish, but I'm afraid of having to redo the project in windows phone 8.0 Silverlight. Currently I am having problem in admob where the emulator it works and the device gives the message "nofill". Does anyone know?

Comment: It should work as long as it's a silverlight app. See this ... https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/bEIlUOW7KTU

Comment: but, in the device not work :/